# How to prove that language is decidable?

Tags: formal-languages, turing-machines

Prove or disprove:
The following language $L$ is decidable:

$\{ \langle M, x\rangle: M \text{ is a Turing machine and } M(x) \text{ halts in less than } |x|^2 \text{ steps} \}$

So for proving I need to construct a TM $U$ if it accepts $L$, so $L$ is decidable, otherwise not.

My steps are:

$U$ = "On input $ \langle M, x\rangle$:

1. $i:=1$;

   $n := |x|^2$
2. Simulate one step of $M$ on $w$.
3. If $M$ accepted $w$ then $U$ accepts.

   If $M$ rejected $w$ then $U$ rejects.

   If $i ≥ n$ then $U$ rejects.
4. Else $i:=i+1$; goto step 2."

Because $U$ is a decider machine, $L$ is a decidable language.

Is this solution correct? Or I should do it in another way?

Comment: Can't you just simulate $M$ for $|x|^2 - 1$ steps? Also, you might need to handle the case $|x| = 0$ separately.

Comment: Your solution seems correct. For more feedback, I suggest contacting your TA.

Comment: This question appears to be unsuited for this site because questions of the form: "This is the exercise problem, this is my solution. Please grade!" are not interesting for anyone but you. Please see [this related meta discussion](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/597/), and [these hints](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/) on asking questions about exercise problems. If you want to ask a *specific* question about a *specific* part of your attempt, please edit the question accordingly and it may be reopened. Otherwise, you might want to visit [chat] and get some feedback there.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prove that a language is decidable, it is sufficient to construct a Turing Machine that accepts if the input is in the language. It MUST reject if the input is not in the language.

Additionally, you are required to argue/prove that the Turing Machine constructed does that. Here's a hint: M must just halt on x, for it to be in L. Consider all possibilities of halting.